# StackOverflowError How Can I Resolve This?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
       public Boolean UpdateKontrol2() {
       page2 = fbclient.fetchObject(data[sayfasayisi][0], Page.class);

       pageposts7 = fbclient.fetchConnection(page2.getId() + "/feed",
                    Post.class, Parameter.with("since", "05-12-2013"), Parameter.with("type", "post"));
       pageposts5 = fbclient.fetchConnection(page2.getId()  + "/feed",
                    Post.class, Parameter.with("since", "05-12-2013"), Parameter.with("type", "post"));

       pageposts9 = fbclient.fetchConnection(page2.getId()  + "/feed",
                    Post.class, Parameter.with("since", "05-12-2013"), Parameter.with("type", "post")); 
       // some fetch operations like this :
       update[i - r][0][sayfasayisi] = pageposts5.getData().get(yukarıgecici2).getMessage();
       // some control operations here
        if (sayfasayisi == boyut) {
        sayfasayisi = 0;
        long finishdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long result =finishdate - datestart ;
        if (result<3600000) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3600000-result);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UpdateDeneme.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    return UpdateKontrol2();
```

My code works fine but after 8 or 9 hours I get a `StackOverFlow` error.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function, but there's no base case to return from. In other words, you have this code that returns a boolean, but you never return an actual boolean, you only return the function itself. It looks like you're trying to do something iteratively, but you have no exit condition... basically an infinite loop.

Comment: thanx bro , i understood my mistake but still i want to ask, if i use void type method and i write just "UpdateKontrol2()" instead of return UpdateKontrol2() end of the method. Any stackoverflow error happens?

Comment: You'll get the same result. You're calling the same method at the end of itself, never returning / exiting out, because the function calling itself is ALWAYS the last thing it does, leading to a stack overflow. The only reason why it takes so long is because you have a Thread.sleep call.